# EJB Timer & Spring Profiles

Tags: ejb, websphere-7, spring-profiles

I'm running an application which has a background process which runs every 5 minutes. It runs in a clustered environment (WAS 7.1) but the process should only run on one server at a time. For this reason I've opted for EJB Timer using the javax.ejb.TimedObject interface. The timer is initially scheduled via a Web application (Spring MVC) in the same EAR. This has been running fine for over a year.

Recently I have upgraded the application to Spring 3.2.4 and made use of profiles. Now when the server recreates the EJB as part of it's lifecycle it sometimes is complaining that it cannot find one of the bean definitions. This bean happens to be defined twice, once withing a beans tag with a profile of 'live' and another with 'test'. The Web Application that initially schedules the timer uses a contexParam in the web.xml of 'spring.profiles.active' set to 'live'. This ensures the timer initially starts with the 'live' configuration. I suspect that when the server recreates the EJB it is recreating the spring context but the profile parameter is being lost somewhere.

Has anyone come across this before or have any suggestions as to how this might be solved?

Thanks in advance.